# Doxygen @param direction arguments [in],[out],[in,out] example output

Tags: c++, output, doxygen

The optional direction argument for the `@param` command is documented [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdparam) as one of the following:

```
@param[in]
@param[out]
@param[in,out]
```

I do not see in any of the [example sites](http://www.doxygen.nl/results.html) how this information appears in the output. Is there an example of how this information should appear in the output?

Answer (score 24):

For the line:

```
\param[in,out] console_ptr - pointer to input from the console
```

I get:

```
Parameters
    [in,out]    console_ptr - pointer to input from the console.
```

Comment: Is there a page I can access?

Comment: You would need to contact the Doxygen folks or search their forums.

Comment: An easy solution is to write a simple source file with the Doxygen comments, process it with Doxygen and see the output.